# How I can make opencats candidates module's email fields required and unique?

Tags: php, requiredfieldvalidator

I have installed and configured OpenCats successfully. I have added a few customs fields and now everything is working fine.

However, I want to apply some checks on default fields for candidates.

I want to apply two checks on the email field:

1. Required
2. Unique

How can I do that?

Here is an OpenCats Repo https://github.com/opencats/OpenCATS

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, @Dwhitz .  Actually, My Question is related to OpenCats (Open source script). Unfortunately, on stack, there is no tag for OpenCats. So I just added PHP and validation as a tag.